# Found relative path while evaluating include directories of <target> even though it is absolute

Tags: cmake, configuration

I know this is the n'th topic on this matter but I couldn't find anything that helped me. This is the questionable part in my CMakeLists.txt:

...

```
# Headers
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
)
```

...

AFAIK all dirs are absolute, still CMake complains with the error:

```
[cmake]   Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "myproject":
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "c:/dev/myproject/build/src/include"
[cmake]
```

How is that a relative path? Looks pretty absolute to me :/

Answer (score 0):

Solved - The problem was that I was running "cygwin cmake" from `C:\cygwin64\bin`. To "cygwin cmake" every windows path looked like a relative path because the cmake ecosystem was pretending it was unix.

I switched to "mingw64 cmake" (`C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`) and it works.